# How i can make Schedule event alarm in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

How i can make Schedule event alarm in iphone?

Schedule for 365 days and five time in the day. every days have different time

Comment: StackOverflow questions are generally more answerable when written in English. Grammar and punctuation matter. It doesn't have to be perfect, just understandable and clear.

Answer (score 0):

use this idea

```
    NSLog(@"clicked");
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];


[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:MM:SS"];                 //seting the date formater object
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSString* CorrectTime = [formatter stringFromDate:date];     //storing the date into string
NSLog(@"Current Time %@",CorrectTime);

[lab setText:CorrectTime];

 if(!isValue){

        NSTimeInterval seconds=10;       //if 24 * 60 * 60 its for after 1day i.e. 24hrs,60min,60seconds
        NSDate *changed;
        changed = [date addTimeInterval:seconds];

        af60= [formatter stringFromDate:changed];
        NSLog(@"Changed time after 60s %@",af60);

    isValue = TRUE;

NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 5.0];
NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:d interval: 2 target: self selector:@selector(timerTick) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[t release];
 }
```

}

```
 - (void)timerTick{
   NSLog(@"Time Out********************************&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"Yours Time Out" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok",nil];
   [alert show];

  }
```

here i added only 10 sec, after 10 sec it wil pops alertview. like this u should fire your alarm

Comment: I think Blue Stock didn't ask on how to use timer. From the description, he wants to schedule an alarm in iPhone. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the notification.repeatInterval

like this

```
NSInteger index = [scheduleControl selectedSegmentIndex];
     switch (index) {
    case 1:
        notif.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
        break;
    case 2:
        notif.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
        break;
    case 3:
        notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
        break;
    case 4:
        notif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
        break;
    default:
        notif.repeatInterval = 0;
        break;
}
```

This will help you 
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html
Thanks,
Naveed

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the notification.repeatInterval for your code

like this

```
NSInteger index = [scheduleControl selectedSegmentIndex];
     switch (index) {
    case 1:
        notif.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
        break;
    case 2:
        notif.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
        break;
    case 3:
        notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
        break;
    case 4:
        notif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
        break;
    default:
        notif.repeatInterval = 0;
        break;
}
```

This will help you 
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html
Thanks,
Naveed